# Noisy, risograph-style gradients and textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

How can I make a some sort of like... a gradient like this?

[image: noisy gradients]

https://medium.com/@stefanhrlemann/how-to-create-noisy-risograph-style-gradients-and-textures-in-photoshop-in-3-ways-394d6012a93a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Overview:

You can do this by firstly create **Gradient** based on chosen axis (Y in this example) and mix it with some noise (**Voronoi** > **Noise**). You can control base gradient driven by top **Color Ramp** and **Noise** distribution with bottom **Color Ramp**.

[image: nodes]

Comment: Wow! Very good. I'll use it for my next project.